# MultiValueDictKeyError in Django Project

Tags: python, django

**View.py**

```
if req.method == 'POST':
        df = DocumentForm.objects.filter(document_id=id)
        logging.info('LOG: I am here')
        if df.exists():
            for d in df:
                description = req.POST['{}'.format(d.description, False)]
                displayName = req.POST['{}'.format(d.displayName, False)]
                df.update(displayName=displayName, description=description)
        return redirect('/adboard/upd')
```

**HTML File**

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="{{id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

                  {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="row mt-3 mb-3"></div>

                    {% if messages %}

                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">

                      {% for message in messages %}

                      {{ message }}

                      {% endfor %}

                    </div>

                    {% endif %}

                   {% for df in data %}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <small class="text-muted bold-label m-lower">&#123;{{df.field}}&#125;</small>
                        <label for="validationCustom01">{{df.displayName}}</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="{{df.displayName}}" value="{{df.displayName}}" placeholder="Enter Display Name">
                        <label for="validationCustom01">{{df.description}}</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="{{df.description}}" value="{{df.description}}" placeholder="Enter description">

                        <div class="invalid-feedback">

                            Please enter required fileds.

                          </div>

                        <!-- <div class="valid-feedback">

                          Looks good!

                        </div> -->

                    </div>

                    {% endfor %}
                   

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-red btn-block">SAVE</button>
                   
                  </form>
```

What I am trying to achieve is.

Pass a variable form to the user to fill
And I get the result.

I can't tell what the input id/name would be because it's a variable.

But I am finding it difficult getting the value from the view.py file.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
req.POST['{}'.format(d.description, False)]
```

to

```
req.POST.get('{}'.format(d.description, False))
```

Comment: I got null value in column "displayName" violates not-null constraint

Comment: that might be a problem with your Models. if you are passing a null value to a column that doesn't support null values, you get that error.